Chrome Record Audio And Video Using getUserMedia
I am trying to use my chrome addon to record a screen its working fine and recording the video but i cant seem to get it to record the audio from the screen or desktop
this is the code i have now below does anyone know how to record the audio with the video from the tab i have googled and got loads of pages from this website and from some others but after trying to implament there codes its still not recording the audio
                chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(
                ['screen', 'window'],
                function (streamId) {
                  if (streamId == null) {
                    return;
                  }

                  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                    audio: {
                      mandatory: {
                        chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                        chromeMediaSourceId: streamId,
                      }
                    },
                    video: {
                      mandatory: {
                        chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                        chromeMediaSourceId: streamId,
                      }
                    }
                  }).then(stream => {
                    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

                      mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
                        if (e.data.size > 0 && socket.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                          // add data to chunk
                        }
                      };

                      mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
                        stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
                      };

                      mediaRecorder.start(1000);
                      
                  }).finally(async () => {
                    await chrome.tabs.update(message.body.currentTab.id, { active: true, selected: true });
                  });
                });


Computer says No... No recording Netflix etc. Sorry

@VC.One Actually i have found a way to record audio and video from within a chrome tab be it drm content or not while being able to minimize chrome its selfand continue to use the system as normal even playing spotify locally while only capturing the tab audio
not that its being used to record drm content its in fact being used to record company web based software sessions in order to track down and identify what actions are causing specific bugs in the system that is effecting roll out to all departments the recording and playback allows us to recreate all the steps used by the employee

Feel free to share your solution to help other future readers with same issue. If you post it as an Answer then it can be found through search, is community editable, etc. I assume confirming the coding steps or APIs used is enough (eg: is using Screen Capture API or using Chome.tabCapture) is enough for others to make their own code...?

PS: "The recording and playback allows us to recreate all the steps used by the employee" sounds way better than "Random Code Guy wants to record anyone's screen"
